# SetTimeout not returning correct value and Unresponsive script

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, settimeout

Consider that I want to put all Descendant's tagName of an element into an array.

```
var node = document.getElementById('mainbar');
```

However since we are looping through a number of nodes using the function below, I have added a **setTimeout** Function to Timeout the function after every 50 loops.

```
function MyFunction(root){
    "use strict";
     var myarray = [], descendants, descendant, i=1, l;
     descendants = root.getElementsByTagName('*');

     function getParentNode(){
        for(l = descendants.length; i<l ; i++){
          descendant = descendants[i];
          myarray.push({ tagName: descendant.tagName});

         //  After 50 loops, increment i, setTimeout
          if(i % 50 == 0 ) {
            i++;
            setTimeout(getParentNode, 20);
          }

        }
     }

     function init(){
       getParentNode();
       return   JSON.stringify({ nodes:myarray });
     }

      return init();    
   }
```

However, there are two problems:

1. **The complete array (myarray) is not returned.**
2. **Even I have used setTimeout, screen freezes when the process is long.**

How can I solve them? I mean I have used setTimeout so that page does not become unresponsive.

P.S.: You can test the script on Stackoverflow itself as it contains an element with id mainbar.
 I agree that getting the Tagname will not take so long, but I am also calculating some other things like filtered getComputedStyle of each element, which certainly takes noticeable time. I put this question as a proof of concept to understand how to use setTimeout from preventing the script from being responsive

Comment: If you're using `setTimeout`, you cannot synchronously return a result

Comment: @David I am calling getParentnode() in setTimeout. Were you asking something else?

Comment: Your comment says "and break the function", but you don't.

Comment: also, `if(i % 50) {...}` won't just run every 50th loop, it'll run every loop except multiples of the 50th. You need `if(!(i%50)) {...}`

Comment: hmm... wouldn't that conditional be doing the opposite of what you want? `1 % 50 = 1` so on the first iteration it would already start the process over again immediately, and again on each iteration until it reaches 50.

Comment: @BYossarian Sorry. I missed i%50 == 0 part. Edited the question. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I previously used break; But as you can guess its breaking from init() (and not getParentNode) and returning only the first value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring all of the other issues mentioned by others and just answer the question of how to accomplish the asynchronous functionality.  You could introduce the idea of a callback into your code.  Rather than trying to use the result immediately after the call, you pass a function to be called once the result is ready:

http://jsfiddle.net/4CdJ2/

```
function MyFunction(root, callback) {

    /* ... */

    function getParentNode() {
        for (l = descendants.length; i < l; i++) {

            /* ... */

            if (i % 50 == 0) {
                i++;
                setTimeout(getParentNode, 20);
                return;
            }
        }

        // made it out of the loop, must be done
        var result = JSON.stringify({
            nodes: myarray
        });

        callback(result);
    }

    getParentNode();
}

var result = MyFunction(document.getElementById("root"), function(result){
    alert("GOT RESULT: " + result);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. You're still expecting that after you call `getParentNode` in `init`, you'll have your result on the next line. You won't. It won't have been built yet.
2. Basically the same as one: `MyFunction` returning the result of `init` won't work, because `init` schedules asynchronous processing and returns before it's finished.
3. In `getParentNode`, you're looping and scheduling a **new** call to `getParentNode` for every node in the `descendants` list. You're not processing them asynchronously, you're scheduling a huge bunch of calls back all at once.
4. The lists returned by `getElementsByTagName` start at `1`, not `0`.

**If** this needs to be asynchronous, you'll need to refactor `getParentNode` to process one element per call.

But even if a very deeply-nested structure, you're unlikely to need to do this asynchronously, even on large documents it just shouldn't take that long:

```
function MyFunction(root) {
    "use strict";
    var myarray,
        descendants,
        i,
        l;

    descendants = root.getElementsByTagName('*');
    myarray = [];
    for (i = 0, l = descendants.length; i < l; i++) {
        myarray.push({
            tagName: descendants[i].tagName
        });
    }

    return JSON.stringify(myarray);
}
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder: 
1. What should do for case 1 and 2. I know jQuery deffered. But what's the option in Javascript

2. I have started the i from 1 because 0%50 was returning 0. 

3. Can you please put some code, how to achieve that?. That will be really helpful.

Comment: @DeveshKumar: I have to run out the door, but there's a synchronous version in the answer. You shouldn't need an asynchronous one, not in any reasonable DOM.

Comment: @tjcrowder: I agree that getting the Tagname will not take so long, but I am also calculating some other things like filtered getComputedStyle of each element, which certainly takes noticeable time. I put this question as a proof of concept to understand how to use setTimeout from preventing the script from being responsive.